# Errors trying to search a many to many relationship in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm having trouble contructing a query within an many to many relationship... I have these domain classes:

```
class Event {

Appuser creator
static belongsTo = Appuser
static hasMany = [guests: Appuser]
```

and

```
class Appuser {


static hasMany = [friends: Appuser, events: Event]
```

So the idea is a user can have friends, and they can set up and own multiple events, and they can also be guests of other user's events.

My issue is constructing a query to get the list of guests for a particular event...

I've tried in my controller:

```
def guests = Appuser.findAllByEvent(eventInstance)
```

this gives an error

> No property found for name [event] for class

```
def guests = Appuser.findAllByEvents(eventInstance)
```

this gives  an error

> No value specified for parameter 1

Any ideas how to remedy? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Appuser.findAllByEvent` doesn't make sense because there's no `event` property in the class. Dynamic finders can only work with persistent properties. `findAllByEvents` is more likely to work because there is an `events` property (added by an AST transform because of the `hasMany`) but you can't query on collections with dynamic finders; you need to use criteria/where/HQL queries for those.

But you don't need a query at all - just use the `hasMany` property you declared:

```
Event eventInstance = ...
def guests = eventInstance.guests
```

Comment: But he wanted the guests not the events

Comment: I'm trying to get the guest list for an event, not the list of a user's events.

Comment: Sorry, switched the classes. But it's the same thing because there's a `hasMany` on both sides. I updated the answer.